# Pythonのreplace関数で正規表現を用いて複数の文字列を変換する

Tags: python, python3, 正規表現

`replace` 関数を用いて、複数の文章の置換をしたいのですが
頓挫しておりどなたか詳しい方教えていただけますと幸いです。

#### 目的

`msg` に二つ以上の文章を格納し、その文章の中で`正規表現01`に該当する文字列を`正規表現02`に置換したい。

#### コード

以下のスクリプトを試しましたが、うまくいきません。

- `置換したい文字列置換したい文字列`は実際には文章が入りますが、社内秘のためお見せすることができません。
- 正規表現01に関しては`置換したい文字列置換したい文字列\n\n`に値する正規表現がこちらで準備ができているのでこの部分は教えていただかなくても大丈夫です。
- `正規表現02`に関しては`置換したい文字列置換したい文字列\n\n! /item/0001\n\n`←こちらの文章が`/item/master/0001`のようになる正規表現になっています。

```
import re

msg = '置換したい文字列置換したい文字列\n\n! /item/0001\n\n,置換したい文字列置換したい文字列\n\n! /item/0002\n\n'

pattern = re.compile(r'正規表現01')

result = pattern.sub('正規表現02', msg)
print(result)
```

Comment: 「うまくいかない」とは具体的にはどのような状態ですか？まったく置換がされない or 一部が意図した通り置換されない etc... / 社外秘で伏せ字にすること自体は構いませんが、問題を再現できるようなダミーのデータを提示した方が回答も付きやすいと思います。

Comment: ご指摘をいただきありがとうございます。
ちょっとダミーデータを入れられないか確認いたします。

Comment: こちらが参考になりませんか？[Pythonで文字列を置換（replace, translate, re.sub, re.subn）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-str-replace-translate-re-sub/)

Comment: タイトル、質問内容ですが、replcae関数を用いる必要はないと思いますので、訂正したほうが良いと思います。また、文章というのは改行コードを含んだ文字列のことで認識は正しいでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
そちらのサイトを参考にしたのですが、難しく解決までいたりませんでした。

＞文章というのは改行コードを含んだ文字列のことで認識は正しいでしょうか？
はい、おっしゃる通りです！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問の意図と合致しているかは自信がありませんが、以下のような結果となれば良いのでしょうか？

1.正規表現で合致した部分を抜き出す。
2.その抜き出した部分の数字部分をそのまま利用する
3.置換したパターンをもとの部分と置き換える。

ソースコード

```py
import re

Sentence = '\n'.join(
    [
        'なまむぎ なまごめ なまたまご/item/0001\n\n',
        'すももも ももも もものうち/item/0001\n\n ももも すももも もものうち/item/0002\n\n',
    ]
)

print(Sentence)

re_item = re.compile(r'/item/[\d]*\n\n')
res = re_item.findall(Sentence)
if res:
    items = list(set(res))
    for item in items:
        re_item = item
        item = item.replace("/item/","")
        item = item.replace("\n\n","")
        item = f'/item/master/{item}'
        Sentence = re.sub(re_item, item, Sentence)

print(Sentence)
```

出力結果

```
なまむぎ なまごめ なまたまご/item/0001


すももも ももも もものうち/item/0001  

 ももも すももも もものうち/item/0002 


なまむぎ なまごめ なまたまご/item/master/0001
すももも ももも もものうち/item/master/0001 ももも すももも もものうち/item/master/0002
```